# mongodb - $lookup with $if operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I am building a side project. where I want to use nested $lookup and $unwind if certain condition match. I created simple prototype below. some users have numbers and some don't have numbers. I want to do join if the number is not null or undefined

here is the code -

```
users.aggregate([



{
     
        $lookup: "number",
        localField:"user.number",
        foreignField:"name",
        as:"number"
     
   }
    {
                $unwind: {
                    path: "$number",
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                }
    }
    ,
   {
     
        $lookup: "countries",
        localField:"number.countrycode",
        foreignField:"name",
        as:"countries"
     
   },

   {

      $unwind:"countries",
      //preserveNullAndEmptyArrays

   },
   $project:{

       name:1,
       number:"$number.phoneNumber",
       countryCode:"$countries.countryCode"


    }
 ])
```

Output:

```
[{

name:"yashraj basan"
number:"123345677",
countryCode:"US"
},
{

name:"krutik basan"
number:"123345679",
countryCode:"FR"
}]
```

Right now i am getting all users who have numbers but i am want both users who have number and who don't have number

Expected output:

```
[{
    
    name:"yashraj basan"
    number:"123345677",
    countryCode:"US"
    },
    {
    
    name:"krutik basan"
    number:"123345679",
    countryCode:"FR"
    },
    {
      name:"dhruvam basan",
      number:"",
      countrycode:""
    },{
     name:"foo bar",
number:"",
countrycode:""
    }]
```

I appreciate all your inputs. thank you

Comment: Can you show some data and expected result?

Comment: @micki i updated question. take a look

Comment: So you're running `$lookup` which works fine but then you want to use `$unwind` and you lose some documents due to missing `country` is that correct?

Comment: right. i want both users who have numbers and who don't have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to run `$lookup` conditionally. You can do it for every user but then when you use `$unwind` you can take advantage of [preserveNullAndEmptyArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#document-operand-with-options) option:

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from:"countries",
        localField:"user.number.countrycode",
        foreignField:"name",
        as:"countries"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: {
        path: "countries",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}
```

Comment: @micki thank you for your input. I tried that solution it is returning me error "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators" whenever I put preserveNullAndEmptyArrays as true.

Comment: @Yashrajbasan can you edit your question and show your code? Seems like something easy

Comment: For both `$unwind`s you need to use an object (`{path: , preserve...: }`) syntax and it should be valid. You can compare with the documentation